# What would be the Mean shortest distance from random points in the right angled triangle to the Hypotenuse.

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry

The problem is to find the average shortest distance of uniformly random points from the hypotenuse in a right angled rectangle.

The distance d shows the shortest distance to the hypotenuse from a random point N (x1,y1). I want to find the average (mean) shortest distance from N random points inside the triangle.

What I have in mind is to integrate the distance formula of point distance to the hypotenuse.
Let P be (0,0) => Q (a,0) and R (a,b)
Then slope of hypotenuse will be $m = \frac{b-0}{a-0} = \frac{b}{a}$

The equation of hypotenuse be **$bx -ay = 0$**.

The distance ***d*** would be $$d = \frac{|b*x_1 -a*y_1|}{\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}}$$

I thought integrating it over x and y for the given range would provide me with the mean shortest distance -

$$D_{mean} = \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{b} d.dx.dy = \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{b} \frac{|b*x_1-a*y_1|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} dx.dy$$

I am stuck in solving it... (given that my approach is the correct one.)

[image: The distance d shows the shortest distance to the hypotenuse from a random point N (x1,y1)]

Comment: Perhaps $A(x-x_1)+B(y-y_1)+C=0$ where $x, y$ expresses the hypotenuse and  $x_1, y_1$ the random point.

Comment: Can you please elaborate upon the steps... so I understand what I am doing wrong or not doing?

Comment: Since $bx - a y \ge 0$ for $(x,y)$ below the line $PR$ and hence within $\Delta PQR$, you can remove the $|\cdots|$ in your integral. The end result is average distance equals to the distance of center of mass of $\Delta PQR$ to line $PR$, $\frac{ba}{3\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$,  which is also one third of the height of $\Delta PQR$ when $PR$ is used as base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $P$ to be the origin.  Then the equation of the hypotenuse is

$ y = \dfrac{b}{a} x , \hspace{15pt} x \in [0, a] $

Now pick a point $ (x_1, y_1) $ such that $ y_1 \in [0, \dfrac{b}{a} x_1 ], then its perpendicular distance from the hypotenuse is

$d (x_1) = \dfrac{ \dfrac{b}{a} x_1 - y_1 } {\sqrt{1 + \left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)^2} } = \dfrac{ b x_1 - a y_1 }{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$

So the average distance is

$ \overline{d} = \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{A}  \int_{x_1=0}^{a} \int_{y_1 = 0 }^{\dfrac{b}{a} x_1} \dfrac{ b x_1 - a y_1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} dy_1 dx_1  $

where $A = \displaystyle \int_{x_1=0}^{a} \int_{y_1 = 0 }^{\dfrac{b}{a} x_1} dy_1 dx_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} a b  $

Integrating with respect to $y_1$,

$\overline{d} = \dfrac{2}{ab \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \displaystyle \int_{x_1=0}^{a} \dfrac{b^2}{2a} x_1^2 dx_1 = \left(\dfrac{b}{a^2 \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right) \left(\dfrac{a^3}{3}\right)  =\dfrac{ab}{3 \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} $

Comment: Thanks a lot :)